# Remove Files to Sync Two folders with Python dirsync

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization

Hi I am using dirsync to sync to folders and upon some testing I noticed there is some functionality that dirsync is missing that I need.

My code:

```
from dirsync import sync

src = "C:/src/"
des = "C:/des/"

sync(src, des, "sync")
```

This works well for copying files from 'src' to 'des' when they are not there, but what I would like is, when I delete files in 'src' and sync the folders, the files should then be deleted in 'des'

Any advice on how to accomplish this, thanks in advance.